# How to batch select rows in ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to batch select rows in ag-Grid?

Specifically, when I first load data into my grid, I also get from the server a list of rows that should be initially selected. Right now, the only way I know of to select them is to:

```
this.state.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
  if (isInitiallySelected(node.data) {
    node.setSelected(true);
  }
});
```

However, this fires an `oneSelectionChange` event for each iteration. This causes some problems in my UI, since I show feedback (a toast) when rows are selected/de-selected.

Is there a way to tell the grid on initial load which rows should be selected?

If not, is there a way via the API to batch-select rows?

If not, is there a way to conditionally silence the `onSelectionChange` event when doing a `node.setSelected()` call?

Comment: I would decouple the showToast logic and in onRowSelected(), I would fire a show toast only when count of initial rows = count of selected rows, after you are done individually selecting them

Answer (score 1):

you can use the param suppressFinishActions to prevent the selectionChanged event.

```
/**
 * Select (or deselect) the node.
 * @param newValue -`true` for selection, `false` for deselection.
 * @param clearSelection - If selecting, then passing `true` will select the node exclusively (i.e. NOT do multi select). If doing deselection, `clearSelection` has no impact.
 * @param suppressFinishActions - Pass `true` to prevent the `selectionChanged` from being fired. Note that the `rowSelected` event will still be fired.
*/
public setSelected(newValue: boolean, clearSelection: boolean = false, suppressFinishActions: boolean = false) {
    this.setSelectedParams({
        newValue,
        clearSelection,
        suppressFinishActions,
        rangeSelect: false
    });
}
```

Comment: MinteLiu.l, please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

`ag-grid` doesn't provide optional events emitting.
But you can create a `hack` for internal handling

```
private initSelectionDone:boolean;

this.initSelectionDone = false;
this.state.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
  if (isInitiallySelected(node.data) {
    node.setSelected(true);
  }
});
this.initSelectionDone = true;

onSelectionChange(...){
    if(this.initSelectionDone){
        ...your logic here...
    }
}
```